# How do you include a password for Amazon DynamoDB access in iOS?

Tags: ios, authentication, amazon-dynamodb

A part of my iOS app needs to save users' email addresses in a central database. I've elected to use Amazon DynamoDB. I don't need each app user to have their own credentials, I just would like to have one username/password for the app itself to write back to the database.

Using the Amazon sample code, I put this in the app delegate:

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider credentialsWithRegionType:CognitoRegionType
                                                                                               identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:DefaultServiceRegionType
                                                                      credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Created a full access role in IAM Manager, then use the following code to write to the database:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];


NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
NSString *emailAddress = ([self.emailAddress.text length]>0)?self.emailAddress.text:@"a@b.com";


EaSLIEmailList *emailListItem = [EaSLIEmailList new];
emailListItem.UUID = uuid;
emailListItem.EmailAddress = emailAddress;

NSMutableArray *tasks = [NSMutableArray array];
[tasks addObject:[dynamoDBObjectMapper save:emailListItem]];

[[BFTask taskForCompletionOfAllTasks:tasks]
 continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
     if (task.error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: [%@]", task.error);
     }

     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

     return nil;
 }];
```

This works absolutely fine, but I'm not sure that this is secure. I thought I should create a user and password to embed in the app.

I'd appreciate anyone's guidance on the best and simplest way to do this.

(My concern was that if I don't do this, then someone could access the database without going through the app).

Answer (score 0):

Your backend could call the [AWS Security Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/Welcome.html) to generate temporary credentials, which you then pass to the mobile device. These credentials could be assigned permissions to only specific items in DynamoDB (so even if the credentials were compromised, they would not reveal any other data).

Comment: Thanks John, I'll check it out and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Amazon Cognito can also be used to generate temporary credentials when an app user logs in: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html